# Center ViewPager horizontally

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to center the content of a `ViewPager` horizontally when the pages don't fill the width of the device. I'm setting the width of each page according to the width of the image contained within it, and inflating the xml inside a `RecyclerView` I've tried with every combination of `center_horizontal` possible, and nothing seems to work; apart from the contents being on the left of the screen, when I try to scroll the pages they flicker between right and left.

Is there any way I can do this without setting padding to the `ViewPager` programatically? Why do `android:layout_gravity:"center_horizontal"` or any of it's synonyms not work?

Below is my code in the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I see:
[image: What I see]

What I want to see:
[image: What I want to see]

Comment: Modify the views that you are adding to the view pager. Use a relative layout as the root, and center the image view inside of that.

Or if you are already trying to do something like that, could you share the xml for the views that you are adding to the view pager?

Comment: But it's not the content of the pages what I want to change, but the position of the pages in the screen instead. I could just put margins to the sides of the views, but I think that would be a horrible solution to the problem :/ Of course, if there is no other solution, I guess I would have to do just that, or change the padding of the `ViewPager`

Comment: Hmm.. I guess I may have misunderstood your problem. Could you a simple image example of what you are wanting to see vs what you are seeing?

Comment: There. Maybe now it's clearer?

Comment: Ooooh, yeah. I was thinking that there was just going to be one view per screen. That is a bit tricker. I would have done the same thing you did with your layout as my first try. I'll see if I can't figure out a solution over lunch.

Comment: So, are you making all of the "pages" be items in the RecyclerView, and then adding the RecyclerView as a single page in the ViewPager?

Comment: Nope, I'm adding the ViewPager in the RecyclerView, and then making the pages be pages in the ViewPager.

Comment: It seems to me that it might be better to just use a scroll view to lay them out. It would be easier to control, and you could easily achieve the look you want.